# When a conversion operator is needed c++?

Tags: c++, debugging

I don't really understand why I get this error when I compile the code below:

> error: no match for call to '(Integer) (int)'
>   a = f((int) a);

I'm always confused if I need to declare the return type of `operator+` and `operator=` as `Integer&` or just `Integer`, and when to declare a conversion operator in my class. If it's possible, what are all the implicit conversions of an object without a cast?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Integer{
  int x;
public:
  Integer(int e): x(e) {};
  Integer(const Integer &e): x(e.x) {};
  Integer& operator=(const Integer &e) {
    x = e.x;
    return *this;
  }

  Integer& operator+(const Integer &e) {
    x = x + e.x;
    return *this;
  }

  operator int () {
    return x;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Integer &e) {
    return os << e.x; //corrected
  }
};

int f ( int i ){
  return i + 1;
}

int main (){
  Integer e (1);
  Integer f =2;

  Integer a = e + f ;

  a = f(a); //f the function
  std :: cout <<"a vaut : "<<a << std :: endl ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a function `f` and an `Integer f` - which one are you trying to access in `f((int) a);`?

Comment: I'm trying to call the function f

Comment: Well your code is not doing that. Since `Integer f` is in the closest scope it tries to access that object instead. That's why you should avoid single letter names (and naming objects and functions the same way)

Comment: It's actually an exercise with missing functions in the class Integer and I need to write functions inside the class in order to execute the main function work. So, I can't really change the names of the objects or the function f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stems from having a function (`int f(int)`) and an object (`Integer f`) with the same name.

Since the object is closer in scope than the function the compiler tries to use it first, in particular it tries to find an `operator()` overload on it that would fit the parameter `a`. Since that doesn't exist it reports the error you see.

The cleanest solution would be to use clear and distinct names for objects and functions (instead of one letter names).

Assuming that for some reason you could not change them (which may happen in more complicated projects) the alternative is to use the scope resolution operator `::` - in your particular case it would be:

```
a = ::f(a);
```

Comment: It's actually an exercise with missing functions in the class Integer and I need to write functions inside the class in order to execute the main function. So, I can't really change the names of the objects or the function f.

Comment: In that case you need to contact whoever gave you that exercise to clarify. With the provided `main` it is not possible to call the function `int f(int)` directly due to the issue described in this answer. The only other option to get it to compile would be to add an overload of `operator()` to the class `Integer`

Comment: so a = f(a) is equivalent to a.operator=( a.operator(f) ) ?

Comment: Close, it's `a.operator=( f.operator()(a) )`

Comment: Ok, thanks! What about the implicit conversion? when a conversion is really not needed? Because a lot of times I see objects passed as their attributes without even a cast

Comment: I don't understand the question. Implicit conversions happen implicitly. Since you have an implicit `operator int` it will always be implicitly called when you use an `Integer` object where an `int` is expected

Comment: For example if I don't have the operator int. When an implicit conversion is allowed ?

Answer (score 3):

The compilation error comes from the naming conflict between one of the variables and a function, as already pointed out by others in the comments, and in the other answer. Just rename the function or the variable.

But this is not the only problem.  Once this is corrected, you will face an endless recursion in your stream inserter, because it recursively calls itself.  Just correct it into:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Integer &e) {
    return os << e.x;  // not e !!!
}
```

Finally, it's not a problem yet,  but `operator+` should return a new Integer by value, and not the reference to the current object. Otherwhise, you may get some nasty surprises in more complex expressions.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I made a mistake I wanted to call e.x. But for the naming conflicts, I can't really change the names since it's an exercise where I need to make the main code work and only add functions in the Integer class.

Comment: @Sydney.Ka Thank you for this feed-back. Indeed, if the names cannot be changed, you should accept UnholySheep‘s answer, which addresses this constraint. By the way, you do not need to explicitly cast to int in the function call (as in the error message and probably in your original code).